# How to combine AVG, IF and GROUP BY in a query

Tags: mysql

I have a relational db with 3 tables. The first one, `Categories` has the type of items of a store like veggies, meat, cheeses. The second one, `Clients` has all the clients that had bought in the store. The last one, `Cart`, has a relation with the client id, category id and the amount of money a client spent in the store.

I need to print a report, using MySQL to know how much spent each client in a category. The report should look like

```
+--------+---------+------+---------+
| Client | Veggies | Meat | Cheeses |
+--------+---------+------+---------+
| Tom    | 1000    | NULL |    1500 |
| John   | NULL    | NULL |    2000 |
| Alice  | 1000    | 1000 |    1000 |
+--------+---------+------+---------+
```

Right now, I'm using the following query

```
SELECT client.name AS Client, 
       category.name AS Category, 
       AVG(cart.subtotal) AS Total 
  FROM cart 
       INNER JOIN category ON category.id = cart.id_category 
       INNER JOIN clients ON clients.id = cart.id_client 
 GROUP BY cart.id_client,
          cart.id_category
```

But I get this:

```
+--------+----------+-------+
| Client | Category | Total |
+--------+----------+-------+
| Tom    | Veggies  |  1000 |
| Tom    | Cheeses  |  1500 |
| John   | Cheeses  |  2000 |
| Alice  | Veggies  |  1000 |
| Alice  | Meat     |  1000 |
| Alice  | Cheeses  |  1000 |
+--------+----------+-------+
```

Comment: Why should the report look 'like that'?

Comment: @Strawberry because it is uncomfortable to read

Comment: It's why we tend not to use SQL for presentation

Comment: You would have to do an awkward UNION to get the category names at the top. And that would only work if your categories never changed (or you would have to add another union each time you add a new category). @Strawberry is correct, don't use SQL for presentation.